# Unity Random Map Generation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a random map, and I have two scripts. In the first script, if the created object is in contact with another object (returns true for isTouching), I want it to stay in that position, but it's getting stuck in an infinite loop.

```
public class MapGen : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefab1;
    public bool isPrefab1Touching;
    Vector3 prefab1Position;

    private void Update()
    {
       
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            prefab1Random();
        }
    } 


    public void prefab1Random()
    {
       
        GameObject newObj;
        int counter = 0;
        int randomx = Random.Range(0, 10);
        int randomy = Random.Range(0, 10);
        prefab1Position = new Vector3(randomx, randomy);
        newObj = Instantiate(prefab1, prefab1Position, Quaternion.identity);

        while(true)
        {
            prefab1Position = new Vector3(randomx, randomy);
            newObj.transform.position = prefab1Position;
            counter++;

            if (newObj.GetComponent<CheckSurrounding>().isTouching)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (counter == 10000)
            {
                Debug.Log("stop infinite loop");
                break;
            }
        }


    }
}
```

The second script that carries the variable "isTouching."

```
public class CheckSurrounding : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isTouching;
    public Bounds bounds;
    public LayerMask GroundLayer;

    void Start()
    {
        bounds = gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>().bounds;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        isTouching = Physics2D.OverlapBox(transform.position, bounds.size, 0f, GroundLayer);
    }

    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireCube(bounds.center, bounds.size);  
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is actually to create an object at a location if it is in contact with a place that is the ground, thus preventing objects from stacking on top of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere in your loop will "isTouching" be updated.  It's value will ALWAYS be the default assigned at creation, which is false.  Perhaps you want "isTouching" to be a method, so it's value is computed every time it is called.  Or, perhaps you should call `Update()` after you change the transform.

Comment: But isn't "isTouching" already in the "update" part of the "checkSurrounding" function? When I use it like that, doesn't it directly take the value that is there?

Comment: `isTouching` is just a static variable.  It gets initialized to "false", and only gets updated when `Update` runs.  In your `prefab1Random` function, `Update` is never going to get called, so `isTouching` is never going to be changed.  It will always be false.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that it kept entering the while loop each time, reading the isTouching value correctly, but it wasn't creating a different position each time. The problem was solved when I did it this way.

```
public void prefab1Random()
    {
        GameObject newObj = Instantiate(prefab1);

        int counter = 0;              

        while (true)
        {
            int randomx = Random.Range(0, 10);
            int randomy = Random.Range(0, 10);
            prefab1Position = new Vector3(randomx, randomy);
            newObj.transform.position = prefab1Position;
            counter++;
            bool isTouching = newObj.GetComponent<CheckSurrounding>().check();

            Debug.Log(newObj.transform.position);
            if (isTouching)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if(counter == 10000)     
            {
                Debug.Log("Uygun Pozisyon Bulunamadı");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI, this is exactly what I suggested.  Replace the fixed variable with a method that computes the value each time.